# spring validation configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, spring-modules

i have a problem with a small spring project, it worked fine until i tried to add the Validation framework 
So i addedd adding the jar: `spring-modules-validation0.8.jar`
And the following in `servlet-context.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

       <!-- Enable annotation-based validation using Bean Validation Framework -->
    <!-- Using these instead of vld namespace to prevent Eclipse from complaining -->
    <bean id="configurationLoader"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader"/>
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator" mvc:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader"/>

    <!-- Load messages -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        mvc:basenames="errors"/>

        <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
        <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    </beans>
```

it now throws:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:655)
```

root cause

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for attribute [configurationLoader-ref]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:59)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findDecoratorForNode(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:119)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.decorate(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:97)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1372)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1339)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:261)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:655)
```

I have tried to follow the stacktrace but i cannot find the BeanDefinitionDecorator

Do you have any hints?

Thank you

Comment: Generally this error means the element is not found in the namespace you are referring to. **configurationLoader-ref** is not found in the namespace **mvc:** in your case

Answer (score 1):

The spring module validation configurations you have in the `servlet-context.xml` seem to be the same with the `contact-servlet.xml` found in this [tutorial](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-bean-validation-framework-3.html) with the only difference being the namespace of the `configurationLoader-ref`. Have a look in this tutorial to see the further setup, it has worked for me.